# Converting argv back to a single string

Tags: c++, winapi, command-line

I'm writing a (Win32 Console) program that wraps another process; it takes parameters as in the following example:

```
runas.exe user notepad foo.txt
```

That is: `runas` parses `user` and then will run notepad, passing the remaining parameters.

My problem is that `argv` is broken down into individual parameters, but `CreateProcessAsUser` requires a single `lpszCommandLine` parameter.

Building this command line is probably not as simple as just joining `argv` back together with spaces. Any pointers?

This is just an example. My first argument isn't actually a user name, and might have spaces in it. This makes manually parsing the result of `GetCommandLine` tricky.

Similarly, a naive concatenation of `argv` won't work, because it needs to deal with the case where the original arguments were quoted and might have spaces in them.

Comment: I'd say "joining argv back together with spaces" would be fine. What makes you think otherwise ?

Comment: Benoît, because it wouldn't work for `runas.exe user notepad "foo bat.txt"`.

Comment: Don't forget to quote any args containing spaces

Comment: @avakar: Actually it would, but only because (as I just found out) notepad is odd. Try it: "notepad foo bar" (without the quotes) attempts to load a file called "foo bar.txt". Scary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Manually recombining them is hard:**

You could try to re-combine them, I think it would work, but be sure to following [the same command line escaping rules that windows has](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17w5ykft.aspx).  This could be more than the trivial solution you're looking for.

Also if there are any parameters that have spaces in them, then you would want to join them to the string with quotes around them.   Here is an example of a strange escaping rule:  if you have --folderpath `"c:\test\"` then the last backslash has to be doubled --folderpath `"c:\test\\"`.

**If you are using MFC:**

You can can get the value you want from your derived CWinApp's theApp.m_lpCmdLine.  Note you could still access them the other way too with __argc, and __argv or [CommandLineToArgvW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776391(VS.85).aspx).

**If you are using Win32 only (even without a GUI):**

You can get it from [WinMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633559(VS.85).aspx).  Which can be your program's entry point.

Note you could still access them the other way too with __argc, and __argv or [CommandLineToArgvW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776391(VS.85).aspx).

**If you must use a console based application with main or wmain:**

The Win32 API [GetCommandLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683156%28VS.85%29.aspx) seems to be the way to go.  You would need to still parse this to get past the .exe name though.  Take into account quotes around the exe name/path too.  If there are no such quotes at the start, then just go to the next space for the start.

Comment: Concatenating argv with spaces seems to work; if argv[i] contains a space, I quote that particular value. I've tried a couple of obvious edge cases, and it looks good so far.

Comment: Here's a discussion of the mess that is command-line escaping on Windows: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/twistylittlepassagesallalike/archive/2011/04/23/everyone-quotes-arguments-the-wrong-way.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [GetCommandLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683156(VS.85).aspx) function.

Why not use 'WinMain' instead of 'main'? This should give you the string in the format you want.

Comment: The result of the GetCommandLine call should be processed though before being passed to the next CreateProcess call. The first argument should be removed. Beware that the program name could be wrapped with double quotes.

Comment: In this particular case, the first two arguments need to be removed - the name of the executable and also the user name.

Answer (score 1):

There is Win32 API call that returns command line: [GetCommandLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683156(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have a string allocated with enough space then use strcat on each item in the list.  Yes, it is as simple as joining them back together with spaces.

Edit: Of course, you would need to enclose any items containing spaces within quotes.

Comment: For his example, yes it would.  The caveat of surrounding any items containing spaces with quotes would see you right on this one...